# Asynchronous Compression Library for Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, asynchronous, compression

I'm looking for Asynchronous Compression and Decompression Streaming.  By asynchronous I mean it supports BeginRead, EndRead, BeginWrite, and EndWrite.  The only library that I've found that claims to is the [native .NET classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx).  (I haven't tried them out yet, but it looks like they support it).  I'm hoping to write this for the Compact Framework version 2.0, which doesn't contain the native compression classes.  I'm aware of [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) and [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx), but neither support the asynchronous functions, from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a commercial library, check out [Xceed Zip for .NET](http://xceed.com/Zip_Net_Intro.html).

It has support for batching (Begin/End) and events. It's a really nice library with support for both full and compact frameworks.